# Keycloak .net 5 api service

Tags: asp.net-core, keycloak, openid

I've been trying to get Keycloak working with the following setup:

- Angular Front End

  - I was able to get this working, it goes the keycloak login screen comes up and after login, I'm able to see the token and pass it to my api.
- ASP .NET 5 Service

  - This is a simple api that should authenticate the bearer token and return the value in the controller.  This is the part that is giving me fits.

My client id is api, so thought that was what was supposed to be there, but it wants what is in the Aud property of the JWT.  In my case it was "account".  From what I can tell, it validates the jwt and works if I make apiName = "account" but I don't even need a client secret so something isn't working "right". I'm just not sure what is going on now.

Here is the code:

```
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
    {
        //base - address of your identityserver

        options.Authority = Configuration["Authentication:KeycloakAuthentication:ServerAddress"] + "/auth/realms/" + Configuration["Authentication:KeycloakAuthentication:Realm"];

        //name of the API resource

        options.ApiName = "account";
        options.ApiSecret = Configuration["Authentication:KeycloakAuthentication:ClientSecret"];
        options.EnableCaching = true;
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

        })
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
        options.Cookie.Name = "api.cookie";
    });
```

Plus I have this in the Configure method:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Keycloak, then you shouldn’t be using `AddIdentityServerAuthentication`. That method is explicitly configured to work with IdentityServer setups. But you are using Keycloak as your authentication provider, so there is no need to add IdentityServer into the mix as well.

Instead, you should just use the JWT Bearer authentication scheme directly. Something like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = Configuration["Authentication:KeycloakAuthentication:ServerAddress"] + "/auth/realms/" + Configuration["Authentication:KeycloakAuthentication:Realm"],
        options.Audience = "account",
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    });
```

With JWT bearer authentication, your server already receives a token that was retrieved outside of your application (in your case, the user retrieved it through the Angular client from Keycloak). So you do not need to enter a trust relationship with the authentication provider in your server; you only need to *verify* a token. And for that, you need neither a client id nor a client secret. You only need to know what the authority itself is, so the server can retrieve information (like a signing key) from it to *verify* the token.

Depending on your Keycloak settings, you might want to configure the `TokenValidationParameters` as well, so that you can add further checks to the token. But other than that, you don’t need to do anything else. Since you are using a stateless bearer authentication, you also don’t need to configure the cookie authentication scheme.